# Android Q - How to get External SD Card Public Download directory path

Tags: android, android-10.0

If I understand correctly, in Android Q your app can read/write to the downloads directory both on non removable storage using api:

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
```

which translates to

```
 /storage/emulated/0/Downloads
```

Or the public downloads directory on removable storage (new in Android Q), i.e.

```
/storage/08E7-324HI/Downloads
```

How do I get this second directory using the API?

Comment: really? i can read/write to downloads directory in emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()) and [Environment. getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(String type)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)) methods are deprecated and calling them on an Android Q (or later) device will return a null [File](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File) object.

As you can see in the table below (taken from the Android Developers documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files/external-scoped)) the best way to now access the "Downloads" directory is by means of the [Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider):

[image: Summary of how scoped storage affects file access]

Opening a file by means of the [Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider) is a two-step process.

Firstly, fire off an intent to launch the system's file picker as follows:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
intent.type = "*/*"
startActivityForResult(intent, OPEN_DOCUMENT_REQUEST_CODE)
```

Secondly, listen out for the result in your activity's [onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)) method as follows:

```
if (requestCode == OPEN_DOCUMENT_REQUEST_CODE) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        val uri = data?.data

        if (uri == null) {
            showAlertDialog("Error", "Got back a null URI")
            return
        }

        val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)

        if (inputStream == null) {
            showAlertDialog("Error", "Failed reading the contents of the selected file")
            return
        }

        // TODO: read the input stream as makes sense in your application
    } else {
        showToast("No file selected")
    }
}
```

You can refer to the [Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider) developer guide to similarly see how to create, edit or delete a file.